# Apache, Server Side Includes (SSI) with if expr condition

Tags: apache, ssi, server-side-includes

```
<!--#if expr="$SERVER_NAME = /domain.yyy/" -->
```

This works if my domain name is domain.yyy or mydomain.yyy.

How should I write that if it should work only when my domain name is exactly domain.yyy - not mydomain.yyy or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
<!--#if expr="$SERVER_NAME = 'domain.yyy' || $SERVER_NAME = 'www.domain.yyy'" -->
```